# Can't connect device to localhost

Tags: java, android, tomcat, localhost, ipconfig

I'm trying to connect my real android device to local server.
So at the beginning I connect all devices to 1 network via Wi-Fi.

Next step is copy IPv4 from ipconfig.

Now I'm entering myIpv4:8080 into browser in my android Device and I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

I forgot something ? What can be wrong ?

I should get JSON object like in PC browser.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish ? see the phone through your browser?

Comment: I should get JSON object like in PC browser

Comment: so you have a json uploaded to a website and you need to pull it up to your phone ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)

Comment: I just want to see the json in the browser :)

Comment: @MilanPansuriya it's not a duplicate, I did the same as in your link and now is the problem

Answer (score 0):

can you check your web server is listening on a 0.0.0.0 or just localhost?
Localhost is a loop back IP for every machine. If a webserver is listening to Localhost interface, it only accepts network request from the machine it runs on. Your Android request may be ignored.

Comment: how to check this ? it's springboot webservice rest api

Comment: can you check if your machine's IP and iphone's IP to be on the same network?